# How to make thread runs without any interruption

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method and I want to run a thread by calling the method. But I can run a thread. But now my problem is I want my thread to run even if I call the method multiple times. For example I'm calling a method which calls the thread method and it starts run. Now I'm calling the method again and this should not cause the thread to run fro first rather it doesn't affect the previous running thread. I thought of using  Thread.isAlive();. But still stuck.

```
class MyRunnableThread implements Runnable{

    public static int myCount = 0;
    public MyRunnableThread(){

    }
    public void run() {
        while(MyRunnableThread.myCount <= 10){
            try{
                System.out.println("Expl Thread: "+(++MyRunnableThread.myCount));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                System.out.println("Exception in thread: "+iex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
public class RunMyThread {
    public void call(){
        System.out.println("Starting Main Thread...");
        MyRunnableThread mrt = new MyRunnableThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(mrt);
        t.start();
        while(MyRunnableThread.myCount <= 10){
            try{
                System.out.println("Main Thread: "+(++MyRunnableThread.myCount));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException iex){
                System.out.println("Exception in main thread: "+iex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of Main Thread...");
    }
}


public void CallThreadCaller()
{
   call();
}
```

Now I'm calling the call() method again and 
it should not affect the previous thread running. It should check if its running or it should start the thread. But how to check if a thread is already running if we start a new instance.

Comment: Have you tried anything on this. Can you show us sample code which you have tried.

Comment: Create an instance of the class you need for each thread, have each thread interact with it's own instance of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is if you are using Java 1.7 is to use a `ExecutorService` namely `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.

This has only one live thread with an Unbounded queue. So your subsequent invocation of your method calls will be queued.

```
private ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void yourMethod() {
    ex.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Your logic
        }
    });
}
```

Now even if you call `yourMethod` multiple times the first thread have to finish before subsequent threads can start.

Comment: but this queue will become a problem. ?

Comment: You can check if the thread is running with complicated logics, but I think this solution will solve your problem elegantly.